# React Drag and Drop possible without external library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I am trying to find file upload with normal react code without using any external dependencies or plugin.

Can anyone help me to sort out drag and drop file upload in react. Any fiddle will be highly appreciated

I just tried with normal file upload and increase the padding

```
<input type="file" className="inputFile" name="file"  onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChangeHandler(event)} />
```

and css as

```
.inputFile {
    left: 29%;
    padding: 10px 159px 433px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

now i have the region ,but while dragging and dropping onChange is not getting triggered 
This is my react code

```
onChangeHandler(event){
        this.setState({
          selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        });
        this.onClickHandler();
      };
      onClickHandler = () => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile);
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:8080/api/assetlibrary/ms/upload", data, {
            onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
              this.setState({
                //loaded: 100
                loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total) * 100
              });
            }
          })
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                warningToast:true
            })
            setTimeout(() => {this.setState({warningToast:false})},5000);
          });
      };
```

Can anyone help me to sort why onChange is not getting triggered on drag and drop.Any working fiddle will be highly appreciated.

Note:Please dont have any external react dependeny/plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it fine, but you should be using `onDrop()` [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) instead of `onChange()`.

This will do:

```js
<input
  type="file"
  className="inputFile"
  name="file"
  onDrop={e => this.props.onChangeHandler(event)}
/>
```

Here you have a fiddle to test it:

[image: Edit nice-grass-8zts0]